# Statically link Qt5Core

Tags: c++, linux, qt, static, linker

I'm trying to compile someone else's project that was created using Qt.

I am able to run qmake and make, and create an executable that works on my Linux machine. However, this executable will not work on other linux machines.

When I try to run the executable on a different machine it complains about missing .so files, namely, libQt5Core.so.

Therefore, I think I need to compile it statically. I can modify the makefile created by qmake, and place a -static flag infront of the libs, which include lpthread lQt5Core.

I cannot find any way to run this new make file without an error being thrown telling me that the linker was unable to find Qt5Core. I've been at this for a couple of hours now and I am all out of new ideas.

Any input will help, thanks.

Comment: If you want to link to Qt statically, you need to build Qt itself statically. See [this](http://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW), for example.

Comment: just install the qt-runtime packages on these other linux machines or create a package containing these shared objects. Better is definitly jus install the correct qt runtime packages from your distribution